# React native "prefetch" data?

Tags: list, reactjs, redux, fetch, native

Is there a way to have the data already loaded before displaying it in a list? We have a FlatList which loads all the countries by doing a fetch in the componentWillMount() but this takes a split second to load and render the list. Is there a way to already have this data loaded so when this list is displayed (it's currently in a nested stack navigator) the list of countries are already there? We did consider loading it in the root screen and passing the state down as a prop with the data but it doesn't feel "right" way.

I have a feeling this is something Redux would be useful for but we don't currently use it.

Thanks all!

Comment: With redux I would load anything I want pre-fetched in the root app and it would be available as a prop to FlatList when it is mounted, so i think to achieve it without redux loading in the root screen and passing as a prop is the equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to show while the countries are being fetched? If you won't want anything at all you could do something like this:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        fetch("example.com/countries")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(countries => this.setState({ countries }));
    }

    render() {
        const { countries } = this.state;
        return !countries ? null : <FlatList data={countries}/>;
    }
}
```

Before the fetch has completed, the render method will return `null` and React won't render anything.